Copy from Azure Storage Explorer in Azure Data Factory: query table beforehand
I have on the Azure Storage Explorer a daily updated csv file from an API request. By using Azure Data Factory I want to copy this table to PostgreSQL. This can be done with a Copy Activity. However, I want do some modifications beforehand, because else the table in Postgres will become too large. Example of the table:



ID
ReadDate
MeterName
Value




AAA
2024-11-13 22:00:00-05:00
Meter1
20


AAA
2024-11-13 16:00:00-05:00
Meter1
10


BBB
2024-11-13 22:00:00-05:00
Meter1
40


BBB
2024-11-13 22:00:00-05:00
Meter2
60



I want to:

Get only rows with Meter1 reads.
Get the latest values per ID.

So in the tabel above I only need row 1 and 3.
Since the tabel is daily updated via the API, I would like to overwrite in PostgreSQL the newest values. But we have to take into account that for some days a meter read can be missing for an ID.
Are these modifications somehow possible in Azure data factory before copying it to PostgreSQL?

Have you tried anything?

@Bhavani Yes, in the Copy Activity I have tried under the sink options to insert a query in the tab 'script before copy'. This is not working. And under the source options I do not see any options to apply something like a query/do modifications.

Why don't you use filter activity?

My knowledge about ADF is really basic and limited, but if the filter activity is the way to go then I can delve into that.

on what basis you are taking those rows as latest?

On the latest ReadDate value.

Hi @clubkli Please check the below answer and let me know if it fits your requirement or not?

You can use mapping data flow to achieve your requirement as follows:
Create your CSV file as source dataset, add it source transformation. Add filter transformation to the source to select only rows where the MeterName is Meter1 using this condition:
equals(MeterName, "Meter1")


Data preview of filter transformation:

Add aggregation transformation to get latest date rows, configure it as shown below:

Group by: Id, MeterName columns



Aggregates: ReadDate - max(ReadDate), Value - first(Value)


You will get the data as required as shown below:

If you want to overwrite it into PostgreSQL table use Alter row transformation and select Upsert if , write your condition. Add postgresql dataset to sink transformation and select Allow upsert , select key column as shown below:

Debug the pipeline with dataflow activity with created data flow, the data will copy to the table successfully.

Thanks you for your answer. I am currently going through it and have a question. For simplicity in my question I said I only need one MeterName, but in reality I need two more. How can I write this with the equals() function in the Filter transformation?

Raise new question with your requirement.
